# How to parsing NSDate to RFC 822 always use in English?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, restful-authentication, rfc822

I need to PUT a RESTful to server.
the `Date` must use like `Sat, 19 Jan 2013 04:09:58 GMT`.

in objc I wrote this:

```
NSDateFormatter* _GMTDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_GMTDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[_GMTDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString* theDate = [_GMTDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
theDate = [theDate stringByAppendingString:@" GMT"];
NSLog(@"%@",theDate);
```

it will be output `Sat, 19 Jan 2013 04:09:58 GMT`

but on my real device,the language is Chinese,it will output `周六, 19 1月 2013 04:09:58 GMT`.

How to make it always use in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the locale of the `NSDateFormatter` object.

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"];
[_GMTDateFormatter setLocale: usLocale];
```

Comment: Darn - had same answer and was about to post.  +1