# Display NSDate as "25 May 2014"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I want to show a `NSDate` in the format "25 May 2014". I use the following code, but I need the month in English:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parsing NSDate to RFC 822 always use in English?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411072/how-to-parsing-nsdate-to-rfc-822-always-use-in-english)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy";
```

This link will be helpful:
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table